# Has no implicit type error while reading variable with intent attribute

Tags: module, fortran, implicit

I'm new to Fortran. I'm trying to write a simple module and then test it in the main program. But, this error happens: symbol 'side2' has no implicit type. The same happens for 'side1' and 'hypo'. I am using Simply Fortran IDE. Thanks for your contribution.

```
PROGRAM main
!to test subroutines
use share_data
implicit none
write (*,1) 
1 format (T10, 'Enter the lengths of 2 edges of a right triangle to count the hypotenus:', /)
read (*,*) side1, side2
call hypotenuse(side1,side2,hypo)
write (*,2) side1, side2, hypo
2 format (2X, 'side1=', F10.2, /, 2X, 'side2=', F10.2, /, 2X, 'hypotenuse=', F10.2, /)
END PROGRAM main


MODULE share_data
implicit none
save        
real :: x, avg, std
integer, parameter :: N = 8
real :: arr(N), vec(N)
character(20) :: str
integer :: coun, error

CONTAINS
   SUBROUTINE hypotenuse(side1,side2,hypo)
   !A subroutine to calculate hypotenuse of a right triangle from two other sides
   implicit none

   real, intent(in) :: side1, side2
   real, intent(out) :: hypo

   !calculate hypo
   hypo = sqrt(side1 ** 2 + side2 ** 2)
   END SUBROUTINE hypotenuse

END MODULE share_data
```

Comment: You haven't declared the type of those variables in the main program. Please explain what you think is happening in your code: there are many possible misconceptions in this case and we can better answer you when we know which one you have.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think by using module it's no need to define the variables. I have used other variables of the module in 'main' without defining again. The problem is with the ones which are used in the subroutine of the module.

Comment: Those variables that are declared in the subroutine of the module ... have scope that subroutine only. If you want them to be shared with anything "use"ing that module then they need to be declared above the CONTAINS statement (and not be part of the subroutine argument list). The best arrangement would be to declare them in the main routine and leave your module as it is. BTW, you don't have to keep declaring "implicit none" in all module subroutines if it is done at the start of the module. Also, I think hypotenuse would be better as a function than subroutine.

Answer (score 2):

As @lastchance mentioned in the comments, the names `side1`, `side2` and `hypo` that you declared in the module are actually *dummy arguments* (input parameters) of the subroutine `hypotenuse`, and only have scope inside that procedure.

If the idea is for those arguments be used only inside that subroutine, and not to be shared amongst other procedures, you would better keep them this way, and declare the *actual arguments* (the corresponding variables) in the main program itself.

In short, this would fix the issue you reported:

```
PROGRAM main
!to test subroutines
use share_data
implicit none
real :: side1, side2, hypo    ! <--- declare variables
! (... rest of the code)
```

---

Besides all that, there are a few other suggestions I can give regarding your code, that would align it with the more modern code practices in Fortran.

```
module shared
  implicit none
contains
  ! hypotenuse could be changed from 'subroutine' to 'function'
  real function hypotenuse(side1, side2)
    ! declare the intent of the input parameters
    real, intent(in) :: side1, side2
    hypotenuse = sqrt(side1 ** 2 + side2 ** 2)
  end function
end

program main
  use shared
  implicit none
  ! declare the variables in the call site
  real :: side1, side2, hypo

  write (*,*) 'Enter the lengths of 2 edges of a right triangle to count the hypotenus:'
  read (*,*) side1, side2
  hypo = hypotenuse(side1, side2)
  ! include the format in the i/o statement, so no labels are needed
  write (*,"(2X, 'side1=', F10.2, /, 2X, 'side2=', F10.2, /, 2X, 'hypotenuse=', F10.2, /)") side1, side2, hypo
end
```

Comment: Dear  Lastchance and dear Rodrigo huge thanks for your valuable comments.

Comment: You are welcome. If you found the answer useful, you can mark as accepted, so it will help people who search later with the same question